# Defining multiple variables on one line, does this offer any optimization for the build process?

Tags: c++

Does defining multiple variables on one line offer some form of optimization for the build process or is it simply a choice of coding style?

For example would this:

```
void foo()
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    ..... // do something with a,b,c and d
}
```

Offer any optimization over this:

```
void bar()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    ..... // do something with a,b,c and d
}
```

Comment: If it did give some benefit, any decent compiler would already exploit it.

Comment: <ironic>Yes, of course... far less characters to parse, I see at least 21 less characters to process in the first block</ironic>. Of course that comes at the cost of the time it takes you to maintain the code and the potential for errors...

Comment: Why did Pete delete his reply!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, yes. Smaller input files are faster to read for the compiler. But it would depend a lot on the implementation of the compiler. If you are interested in reducing build times in a compiler independent manner, there are a lot of other optimisations which can be done. **Large-Scale C++ Software Design** by John Lakos is a very good book to read for this.

Answer (score 4):

No optimization worthy of being called such.

The only benefit is slightly fewer characters to load into memory and parse.  I doubt you could even measure the difference.

Use a programming style consistent with the rest of the team, or your personal preference, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a choice of coding style. Personally, I hate defining multiple variables on one line.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of milliseconds, for example, you would see almost no difference. But yes, There's a difference and one line variables are compiled faster than the others.

Comment: I doubt that there is any measurable difference in compilation times for the example in the question. The cost of parsing the extra characters is probably smaller than the jitter in the time that it takes to access the disk to load the file.