# What's the most optimal way to define module variables in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, optimization

What's the best way to declare variables when requiring modules in nodejs? Different well-known node developers follow [different styles](http://dailyjs.com/2012/01/12/style/). For example, TJ Holowaychuk uses this style:

```
(method1)
var connect = require('connect')
  , Router = require('./router')
  , methods = Router.methods.concat('del', 'all')
  , middleware = require('./middleware')
  , View = require('./view');
```

Ryan Dahl, on the other hand, prefers this way:

```
(method2)
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var bench = require('./bench');
```

**NOTE**: My question is not regarding style (which has been covered extensively in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/357981)), but rather about which of the two methods produce the most optimized code (Bonus points if specific to the case of requiring modules). I understand that the difference won't be much, but I do believe it is worth knowing. For example, in C++, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242491/defining-multiple-variables-on-one-line-does-this-offer-any-optimization-for-th) comes to the conclusion that the build process will benefit a little from the smaller number of characters to parse. Apart from that, could there be any other advantage of one method over the other?

Comment: _"which of the two methods produce the most optimized code"_ - optimized by what? Optimized in what sense? Also, what's the essential difference that concerns you between the two examples? Are you asking simply about one `var` statement vs. several?

Comment: @TedHopp optimized in the sense of creating the least amount of execution overhead/memory usage when initiating the variables. And yes, I'm asking about one `var` versus several.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...which of the two methods produce the most optimized code...

I'd be surprised if there were a difference in the actual machine code V8 produces when it compiles the source (other than debug info). I can't believe there's any difference that has any real-world impact from the difference in character count, and the fact that the one produces a single statement using the comma operator to join multiple expressions and the other produces a series of statements (one expression/statement). It really is just a style thing.

For this:

```
// Style 1
var express = require('express')
  , socketio = require('socket.io')
  , bench = require('./bench');
```

The engine actually processes this:

```
// Style 1
var express, socketio, bench;
express = require('express'),
socketio = require('socket.io'),
bench = require('./bench');
```

...e.g., declarations followed by a single statement made up of three assignment expressions joined by the comma operator.

For this:

```
// Style 2
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var bench = require('./bench');
```

The engine actually processes this:

```
// Style 2
var express, socketio, bench;
express = require('express');
socketio = require('socket.io');
bench = require('./bench');
```

...e.g., the declarations followed by three statements with one assignment expression each.

In both cases, the declaration step is completely removed from the initialization, which is really assignment. Upon entry to a context, all variables declared with `var` (and all function *declarations*) create entries in the binding object of the lexical environment of the execution context, prior to any step-by-step code being run. This is why they're sometimes said to be "hoisted," and also why the styles above are largely irrelevant to the engine. (More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html))

And in terms of the difference in the resulting statement(s) once the declarations are factored out, I doubt there's any real difference in the machine code.

Comment: "Upon entry to a context, all variables declared with var (and all function declarations) create entries in the binding object of the lexical environment of the execution context": do you know of a reference to this? Also, thank you for the blog article, that was really interesting!

Comment: @verybadalloc: I should have linked to that, it's covered by [§10.5 of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) (in truly horrible spec-speak). Enjoy. :-)